How to access Autodesk Navisworks .NET API Methods in Powershell 5.1
Have anyone here tried doing automation using Navisworks API in Powershell? I have managed to successfully read Navisworks files, append, save and going through all the elements to check its parameters but even then, i have a vague idea how to properly access the .NET Methods and properties. Sometimes i can't access the methods. Now what i am trying to achieve is automate a clash test using Powershell. Below code is what i have so far.
$NavisworksAPI_API = "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Navisworks Manage 2021\Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.dll"
$NavisworksAPI_DC = "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Navisworks Manage 2021\Autodesk.Navisworks.Controls.dll"
$NavisworksAPI_AUTO = "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Navisworks Manage 2021\Autodesk.Navisworks.Automation.dll"

#Initialize Navisworks API
function Initialize-NavisworksApi {
    Add-Type -Path $NavisworksAPI_API
    Add-Type -Path $NavisworksAPI_DC
    Add-Type -Path $NavisworksAPI_AUTO
    [Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Controls.ApplicationControl]::Initialize()
}

#Clash Test function
function Navis-ClashTest
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [String]$Path
    )

    try{
        $napiDC = [Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Controls.DocumentControl]::new()
        WriteConsole -Value ("Opening file {0}" -f (Split-Path $Path -Leaf)) -Timestamp
        $open = $napiDC.Document.TryOpenFile($Path)
        If(!($open)){
            Throw "Error opening file: {0}" -f (Split-Path $Path -Leaf)
            }
        $DCClash = [Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Clash]::ClashTest()
        $napiDC.Document.Clear()
        $napiDC.Dispose()
        }
    catch{
        $ex = $_.Exception.Message
        WriteConsole -Value $ex -Timestamp
        }
}

I cannot seem to access the methods. In the docs it mentions this namespace Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Class but i have added Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.dll in one of my function. One of the methods is "ClashTest".
I tried to access that one with this code $DCClash = [Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Clash]::ClashTest(). It has error "Unable to find type Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Clash
This one also gives me error: $DCClash = [Autodesk.Navisworks.Api]::Clash.ClashTest()
The Navisworks doc is so confusing. Some part like reading a file is straightforward but not with the clash data. How do I access the .NET methods in Powershell?

If the type name is ClashTest and the namespace is Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Clash, then the full type name is Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Clash.ClashTest.
To invoke a constructor, use the special static member new:
$DCClash = [Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Clash.ClashTest]::new()


Okay got it. I read the docs again and to pull the clash i need to use the extension method GetClash. I tried $DCClash = [Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Clash.DocumentExtensions]::GetClash($napiDC.Document) but it return no data at all.

I just realized in the docs that extensions methods is for C# only. Tried with $DCClash = [Autodesk.Navisworks.Api.Clash.DocumentClash]::ClashInstance($napiDC.Document) but it returns empty data

What do you mean "returns empty data"? Is $null -eq $DCClash? And can you share a link to the relevant version of the docs?

I output the $DCClash but nothing show up. Here is the docs https://apidocs.co/apps/navisworks/2018/87317537-2911-4c08-b492-6496c82b3ed0.htm
